# Are actor based solutions to classic concurrency problems easier to prove correct?

Tags: akka, actor

I'm trying to grasp whether Actor Model, especially popular frameworks like `Akka` provides measurable benefits to software designs.

While I'm not CS theorist, I would feel more confident in this model if it were true that it allows to construct simpler correctness proofs and better specifications. Is reliability a strong point of Agent Model? Would it be a good fit for mission-critical software (health care, avionics etc.)?

My worry is that without some strong and possibly unattainable "global" guarantees like fairness (as I believe actors may exhaust threads available to others) or delivery in finite time, using this model can lead to distributed system that is an order of magnitude more complex to design, describe and debug than alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

As with any other model, Akka reliability depends on the developer. Provided that you use Akka correctly (with the recommended best practices), it is very reliable. And using the actor model correctly is easy and intuitive once you learn the basics.

For example: an actor will hold a thread for too long only if you send him too large messages (large == takes long to process). If you use more smaller messages, the dispatcher will guarantee pretty good fairness. Or, if you need absolute fairness, just use a round robin router.

Delivery in finite time... depends highly on how you choose the mailbox. For example you can prioritize some important messages over others.

Another Akka advantage is easy scalability. If something works for 5 actors, it will work for a 10000 actors. So I believe distributed systems in Akka are easier to design and manage than the traditional models.